# How automatically download current versions of popular software? (like Acrobat, Firefox, Opera)

Tags: automation, update

I'd like to provide LAN users access to set of useful and popular applications (like Acrobat, Firefox, Foobar, putty) but there is one problem - such software is released every few weeks or even often. What is best method of automatically downloading most current versions? Every download page looks differently and only a few has permanent "xyz-current" links.

Disclaimer: I know newer not always means better but in many cases (like browsers) it at least mean safer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is: Ketarin

is has an db of software you can select from to download, and always keep downloading the latest version, also you can add your own, with very flexible settings

check it out over here http://ketarin.canneverbe.com/

Another option would be http://installpad.com/

read more about it on the lifehacker article 
http://lifehacker.com/211373/geek-to-live--automatically-download-and-install-your-favorite-software

Answer (score 1):

[PSI](http://secunia.com/vulnerability_scanning/personal/) and [CSI](http://secunia.com/vulnerability_scanning/corporate/) from [Secunia](http://secunia.com/) will help you keep up to date with critical releases for most popular software packages. PSI is for a single machine, while CSI covers your whole network. Their no-install [OSI](http://secunia.com/vulnerability_scanning/online/) scanner is more limited but handy for quick fix family interventions.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that [freshmeat](http://freshmeat.net/) tracks them (and here I thought they only tracked Open Source applications).  You can sign up with an OpenID (I've yet to do so), and I would not be surprized it you can set up an RSS feed for the applications you are interested in.  It also has nice links that offer direct downloads.

Comment: But this is exactly what I don't want to do - tracking and downloading. It should be fully automated.

Comment: Well, it would be fully automated in tracking, but yes, it is only a partial solution that doesn't address automated downloading.